# GLSL texelFetchOffset works with isampler2D but not usampler2D?

Tags: opengl, glsl, fragment-shader, texture2d, render-to-texture

In a fragment shader, the following compiles fine:

```
uniform isampler2D testTexture;
/* in main() x, y, xoff and yoff are declared as int and assigned here, then... */
int tmp = texelFetchOffset(testTexture, ivec2(x, y), 0, ivec2(xoff, yoff)).r;
```

However, the following does not compile:

```
uniform usampler2D testTexture;
/* in main() x, y, xoff and yoff are declared as uint and assigned here, then... */
uint tmp = texelFetchOffset(testTexture, uvec2(x, y), 0, uvec2(xoff, yoff)).r;
```

The OpenGL 4.2 driver gives the following compiler error message:

**error C1115: unable to find compatible overloaded function "texelFetchOffset(usampler2D, uvec2, int, uvec2)**

This is Nvidia's Linux driver 290.* for a Quadro 5010M -- but I'm wondering if I made a (beginner) mistake and was not working to spec somehow here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `texelFetchOffset` function that takes a `usampler2D` *still* takes an `ivec2` as its texture coordinates and offset. The `u` only applies to the sampler type and return value; not everything about the function becomes unsigned.

And remember: OpenGL doesn't allow implicit conversions between unsigned and signed integer types.

Comment: I thought I'd tried that -- but that must be it. About the conversions, yes I'm forcing the [ #version 420 core ] profile so typically when not doing any explicit casts I'm being warned appropriately. Thanks again!